# Assign two valide classes in one input field form

Tags: login, form-validation

```
js/prototype/validation.js
```

I have two classes: **validate-email**, **validate-mobilePhoneNumber**

```
customer/form/login.phtml
```

In **email input**, the customer can log with the email address or a phone number, so what I would like to do is that when the user enters an email address, I validate the email class: **validate-email** and if he enters a phone number I validate it the phone class: **validate-mobilePhoneNumber**

```
<li>
    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email address or phone number')  ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
         <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry " title="<?php echo $this->__('Email address or phone number') ?>" />
    </div>
</li>
```

**EDIT:** On the basis of the answer of **Jaimin Sutariya**

In **js/prototype/validation.js** we need to add a custom validation

```
Validation.add('validate-email-or-phone', 'Please enter a valid Email address or phone number.', function(v) {
return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || Validation.get('validate-email').test(v) || Validation.get('validate-mobilePhoneNumber').test(v)
```

})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a custom validation to your form field. Add below validation script to your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Validation.add('validate-email-or-phone', 'Please enter a valid Email address or phone number.', function(v) {
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || Validation.get('validate-email').test(v) || /^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/.test(v)
    });
    Translator.add("Please enter a valid Email address or phone number.","<?php echo $this->__("Please enter a valid Email address or phone number."); ?>");
//]]>
</script>
```

You need to replace `validate-email` class with `validate-email-or-phone` in your textbox. This validation will check for email address and for mobile number it will accept all numbers included in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22378736/1409718).

You need to add CSV file for translation.

Comment: Yes, great @Jaimin, just i customized it else look my update. another question: you know how to put a translate function in a validation error `Please enter a valid Email address or phone number.`

Comment: Double "and" in your answer. Small typo. :)

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer please check, I think you know how to add translation using CSV file.

Comment: I want to declare two id for the same input field how to declare?

Comment: @zus, Do you want two ids or want to add two rules on same input field?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Two rules on the same input.

Comment: @zus, You can use `Validator.add` function the second time and add the validation class in your input just like we add multiple classes on an html element.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Thanks for your knowledge sharing.